# Dropbox API - Upload file but no content (Zero KB) inside it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dropbox, dropbox-api

Using Chrome Extensions - Background Javascript, i write below code to Upload images file to my Dropbox. I also provide generated token from my apps.

Below are the codes:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';
var params = JSON.stringify(
    {
        "path" : "/Users/greenbro/images.jpg",
        "mode" : "add",
        "autorename" : true,
        "mute" : false
    }
);
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer < my_DropBox_token>");
http.setRequestHeader("Dropbox-API-Arg", params);
http.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (http.readyState == 4) 
    {
        console.log("Result ===> "+http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send();
```

File was uploaded, **However it's has no content (zero KB)**.

**or i think, file never uploaded, but Dropbox create new file as well as it's path...**

any suggestion ?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You're not actually sending the file data, only its path. Look for correct examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm i have tried searching correct example almost 24 hours but no luck, Could you suggest one ?

Comment: @Greg thank you very much...now solved...